# Get public IP remotely

Tags: networking, ip

I'm thinking of a way to find the public IP of router at home, remotely.

For example if I'm in university and I need to connect to a machine in my home network. How can I get the public IP to connect to it?

To get the IP from that machine I can use something like this website - http://api.exip.org/?call=ip

But how can I send it to myself remotely?

One of the ideas is to write some sort of script that will check my email address for incoming messages. So when I need to know the IP, I just send some email to myself with specific text (or subject). When script will find that specific text, it will send the IP to the same email.

Another idea it to write a script that will upload a new file to the server (for example DropBox) every time the public IP is changed.

Or I can combine those two and email new IP every time it changes (not that often, but still it’s a spam).

What other solutions there can be, and how can I implement them (or the one that I have)?

I have Linux/Unix and Windows machines which I can use. I have no problem in writing code in different languages or looking in to any possible approach.

Comment: Consider using dynamic DNS.

Comment: There are a lot of free dynamic DNS services. You just run a service in the background, and each time your IP changes, it updates your record.

Comment: If you use Gmail, just leave yourself logged in at home and then you can check recent locations for that address. But yes, use DynamicDNS, that is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of home router have dynamic DNS facility , you will find it in your router configuration as DDNS and configuration page you will find list of supported DDNS service ,most popular DDNS service is dyndns.org you have to subscribe there and they will give you tow free subdomain like example.dyndns.org , and after configuring that on your router you can easily from any where ping example.dyndns.org to know your router IP

Comment: dyndns.org isn't free anymore, try using noip.org instead.